# Does the action in electrodynamics and general relativity always take the minimum value?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity

In classical mechanics, the action may not be the minimum value, but the maximum or extreme value. (For example, imagine a particle on the surface of a smooth celestial body.)

Will a similar situation occur in electrodynamics and general relativity? (Consider only electromagnetic or gravitational effects, without other restraints.) And if the answer is no, can a specific counterexample be given?

Comment: This sounds like a homework exercise.

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this question?